# AngleSharp - HTML attributes to Dictionary

Tags: c#, json.net, anglesharp

I want to parse the schema HTML from my webpages to use the JSON internally. So, I am testing AngleSharp for that and almost succeed to get what I need, but having some issue in format of the output. See the My output vs Expected

```
string html = @"<div itemscope itemtype='http://schema.org/Organization'>
  <span itemprop='name'>Google.org (GOOG)</span>
  <div itemprop='address' itemscope itemtype='http://schema.org/PostalAddress'>
    Main address:
      <span itemprop='streetAddress'>38 avenue de l'Opera</span>
      <span itemprop='postalCode'>F-75002</span>
      <span itemprop='addressLocality'>Paris, France</span>
  </div>
    Tel:<span itemprop='telephone'>( 33 1) 42 68 53 00 </span>,
    Fax:<span itemprop='faxNumber'>( 33 1) 42 68 53 01 </span>,
    E-mail: <span itemprop='email'>secretariat(at)google.org</span>
 <span itemprop='alumni' itemscope itemtype='http://schema.org/Person'>
   <span itemprop='name'>Jack Dan</span>
 </span>
 <span itemprop='alumni' itemscope itemtype='http://schema.org/Person'>
   <span itemprop='name'>John Smith</span>
 </span>
</div>";

HtmlParser parser = new HtmlParser();
var htmlDocument = parser.ParseDocument(html);
var scopes = htmlDocument.All.Where(x => x.Attributes.Any(a => a.Name == "itemtype")).ToList();
var dictionary = new Dictionary<string, object>();

foreach(var scope in scopes)
{
    var childrens = scope.Children.Where(x => x.Attributes.Any(a => a.Name == "itemprop"));
    foreach (var child in childrens)
    {
        string prop = child.GetAttribute("itemprop");
        if (!dictionary.ContainsKey(prop))
        {
            dictionary.Add(prop, child.TextContent);
        }
    }
}
//dictionary.Dump();
string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(dictionary, Newtonsoft.Json.Formatting.Indented);
json.Dump();
```

**My Output**

```
{
  "name": "Google.org (GOOG)",
  "address": "\n    Main address:\n      38 avenue de l'Opera\n      F-75002\n      Paris, France\n  ",
  "telephone": "( 33 1) 42 68 53 00 ",
  "faxNumber": "( 33 1) 42 68 53 01 ",
  "email": "secretariat(at)google.org",
  "alumni": "\n   Jack Dan\n ",
  "streetAddress": "38 avenue de l'Opera",
  "postalCode": "F-75002",
  "addressLocality": "Paris, France"
}
```

**Expected**

```
{
  "itemtype": "http://schema.org/Organization",
  "name": "Google.org (GOOG)",  
  "address": {
    "itemtype": "PostalAddress",
    "addressLocality": "Paris, France",
    "postalCode": "F-75002",
    "streetAddress": "38 avenue de l'Opera"
  },
  "email": "secretariat(at)google.org",
  "faxNumber": "( 33 1) 42 68 53 01",
  "telephone": "( 33 1) 42 68 53 00",
  "alumni": [
    {
      "itemtype": "http://schema.org/Person",
      "name": "Jack Dan"
    },
    {
      "itemtype": "http://schema.org/Person",
      "name": "John Smith"
    }
  ]  
}
```

The `.Children` doesn't traverse to all the childrens/and sub children to get all the properties and then attach to the parent itemscope it belongs to. Any suggestion what/where should I change to get the output in expect format.

**Lars Code output:**

```
{
  "name": "Google.org (GOOG)",
  "address": "\n\t    Main address:\n\t      38 avenue de l'Opera\n\t      F-75002\n\t      Paris, France\n\t  ",
  "telephone": "( 33 1) 42 68 53 00 ",
  "faxNumber": "( 33 1) 42 68 53 01 ",
  "email": "secretariat(at)google.org",
  "alumni": "\n\t   Jack Dan\n\t "
}
{
  "streetAddress": "38 avenue de l'Opera",
  "postalCode": "F-75002",
  "addressLocality": "Paris, France"
}
{
  "name": "Jack Dan"
}
{
  "name": "John Smith"
}
```

Comment: It seems that your code not yet covers the `itemscope` feature that they can be nested (`Organization`-> `Address`), and that the `dictionary.Add()` will fail for the second `Alumni` item.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following is my solution.

```
async Task Main()
{
    var html = @"<div itemscope itemtype='http://schema.org/Organization'>
  <span itemprop='name'>Google.org (GOOG)</span>
  <div itemprop='address' itemscope itemtype='http://schema.org/PostalAddress'>
    Main address:
      <span itemprop='streetAddress'>38 avenue de l'Opera</span>
      <span itemprop='postalCode'>F-75002</span>
      <span itemprop='addressLocality'>Paris, France</span>
  </div>
    Tel:<span itemprop='telephone'>( 33 1) 42 68 53 00 </span>,
    Fax:<span itemprop='faxNumber'>( 33 1) 42 68 53 01 </span>,
    E-mail: <span itemprop='email'>secretariat(at)google.org</span>
 <span itemprop='alumni' itemscope itemtype='http://schema.org/Person'>
   <span itemprop='name'>Jack Dan</span>
 </span>
 <span itemprop='alumni' itemscope itemtype='http://schema.org/Person'>
   <span itemprop='name'>John Smith</span>
 </span>
</div>";
    var context = BrowsingContext.New();
    var document = await context.OpenAsync(res => res.Content(html));
    var result = Parse(document.QuerySelector("[itemscope]"));
    var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(result, Newtonsoft.Json.Formatting.Indented);
    json.Dump();
}

void Populate(IElement element, Dictionary<string, object> result)
{
    foreach (var child in element.Children)
    {
        var prop = child.GetAttribute("itemprop");

        if (prop != null)
        {
            var scope = child.GetAttribute("itemscope");
            var value = default(Object);

            if (scope != null)
            {
                value = Parse(child);
            }
            else
            {
                value = child.TextContent;
            }

            if (result.TryGetValue(prop, out var item))
            {
                if (item is List<Object> list)
                {
                    list.Add(value);
                }
                else
                {
                    result[prop] = new List<Object>
                    {
                        item,
                        value
                    };
                }
            }
            else
            {
                result[prop] = value;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            Populate(child, result);
        }
    }
}

Object Parse(IElement element)
{
    var result = new Dictionary<string, object>();
    result["itemtype"] = element.GetAttribute("itemtype");
    Populate(element, result);
    return result;
}
```

Not sure if I get everything right, but my output looks as follows:

```
{
  "itemtype": "http://schema.org/Organization",
  "name": "Google.org (GOOG)",
  "address": {
        "itemtype": "http://schema.org/PostalAddress",
    "streetAddress": "38 avenue de l'Opera",
    "postalCode": "F-75002",
    "addressLocality": "Paris, France"
  },
  "telephone": "( 33 1) 42 68 53 00 ",
  "faxNumber": "( 33 1) 42 68 53 01 ",
  "email": "secretariat(at)google.org",
  "alumni": [
    {
      "itemtype": "http://schema.org/Person",
      "name": "Jack Dan"
    },
    {
    "itemtype": "http://schema.org/Person",
      "name": "John Smith"

    }
  ]
}
```

That matches the expected output. The code for the `Parse` may not be so elegant, but at least it gets the result in a single pass (no other `QuerySelector` required).

I am not sure what the expected input is, but most likely you will need to add some more guards to be protected against weird HTML / input (e.g., check if really `itemtype` is available when `itemscope` was set).

Hope that helps!

Comment: thanks @Florian. This is helpful, but it doesn't fetch the property if they are inside any other element. For example if telephone, fax span tags are inside a <div class='contact'> <span itemprop='telephone'>( 33 1) 42 68 53 00 </span> </div> They are not parsed. What can I change to get all children's.

Comment: Well, I am not sure why the initial example changes, but in my opinion you'll only need an else case inside the loop. I've updated the example.

Comment: Note that this has nothing to do with AngleSharp, but rather how you navigate in a tree. Hope it helps!

Comment: @VikashRathee does that help a bit?

Answer (score 0):

I won't do all the coding here, but the idea could be the recursive way:

```
string GetJsonStringFromItem(ScopeType scope) {
  var localDict = new Dictionary<string, object>();
  var childrens = scope.Children.Where(x => x.Attributes.Any(a => a.Name == "itemprop"));
  foreach (var child in childrens)
  {
      var propValue;
      if (child.HasAttribute("itemscope"))
      {
          // this is the recursion: do the same with the nested scope
          propValue = GetJsonStringFromItem(child);
      } else {
          propValue = child.TextContent;
      }

      string prop = child.GetAttribute("itemprop");
      if (!localDict.ContainsKey(prop))
      {
          localDict.Add(prop, propValue);
      }
  }
  return JsonConvert.SerializeObject(localDict, Newtonsoft.Json.Formatting.Indented);
}
```

Then you call this code in the outermost loop.

Comment: What is ScopeType in your function to pass when calling it ?

Comment: It is the type of the result of `scope.Children.Where(x => x.Attributes.Any(a => a.Name == "itemprop"));`

Comment: I tried that, but it doesn't give the expected output. See my post, I just posted what I got with your code. The address children should be attached to address porperty and so on for alumni as well. But the function give them as separate object

Comment: I updated the code: The value stored in the `localDict`should be the former received `propValue`, not `child.TextContent`. This was an error in my code.

Comment: Still many error, the `if (child.GetAttribute(` should be changed to `if (child.HasAttribute(` and it still doesn't load both alumni names; also the child object are loaded as string instead the object, which doesn't parse the JSON correctly later.

Comment: Well, I see you can find the mistakes yourself. The plan was to show you the idea of the recursive way. The solution for the collision with the keys of the ' alumni' elements is up to you: I won't use a `Dictionary<>` but a `List<>`, this will allow two identical "keys".

Comment: thanks Lars. Yes, this give me an idea, but not the valid solution I can mark it right now. So, I will continue trying with your suggestion to make the final function which give the expected output and post here if I am successful. Appreciate your help. Also, the dictionary value is Object type, so anything can be loaded but key must be unique.